# Data frame text filtering with text

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I need some help with running some filter on some data. I have a a data set made up of text. And i also have a list of words. I would like to filter each row of my data such that the remaining text in the rows will be made up of only words in the list object

```
words

(cell, CDKs, lung, mutations monomeric, Casitas, Background, acquired, evidence, kinases, small, evidence, Oncogenic )


data

ID  Text

0   Cyclin-dependent kinases CDKs regulate a 

1   Abstract Background Non-small cell lung  

2   Abstract Background Non-small cell lung 

3   Recent evidence has demonstrated that acquired

4   Oncogenic mutations in the monomeric Casitas
```

so after my filter i would like the data-frame to look like this

```
data

ID  Text

0    kinases CDKs  

1   Background cell lung  

2   Background small cell lung 

3   evidence acquired

4   Oncogenic mutations monomeric Casitas
```

I tried using the `iloc` and similar functions but I dont seem to get it. any help with that?

Comment: where come from your data ? array ? text file ? did you try something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> df['Text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if i in words]))
0                             kinases CDKs
1                     Background cell lung
2                     Background cell lung
3                        evidence acquired
4    Oncogenic mutations monomeric Casitas
```

Also, I made words a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to improve performance (`O(1)` average lookup time), I recommend you do the same.

Comment: I may have a bad case of `regex`, but I was once advice to flee from the `apply` function like the plague when dealing with the `str` type in favor of the `str` attribute.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock, according to my timings, the apply approach will be faster.  However, you may be correct you should avoid `apply()` for strings, I'm very new to pandas so I am unsure.

Comment: as I mentioned, my solution uses `regex` even though it probably doesn't need it.  But I feel like there's a nicer solution using [Working with Text](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this is the most elegant of solutions, but you could do:

```
to_remove = ['foo', 'bar']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': [
    'spam foo& eggs', 
    'foo bar eggs bacon and lettuce', 
    'spam and foo eggs'
]})

df['Text'].str.replace('|'.join(to_remove), '')
```